# Cannot Install MySQL on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, mysql

I get the error:

> `This installation package could not be opened`

when trying to install MySQL on Windows 7. Everything else installs fine. I have full administrative rights. Why does this happen? Please help me. I can't find any solution, anywhere.

Comment: Try rightclicking on the installation file and run as administrator. Even though you are the admin user on the computer, running as administrator will allow further access to items. Also, are you installing 64bit on a 32bit OS?

Comment: Actually, an admin account has no further access than a user account by default. UAC only allows **process** to elevate to admin privileges.

Comment: @kobaltz: I am running a 64bit OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd review [2.3.3.1.1. Downloading and Starting the MySQL Installation Wizard](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-install-wizard.html)

It has all the instructions you should need.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the installer may be corrupt. Please try clearing your browser cache and/or restarting the download.

Comment: No luck. Any other ideas.

Comment: Make sure you selected the right version and try again - it does work as I use it. or, just try these steps again - try downloading from another machine if you can and verify the md5/signature.